# Round Javascript Float number to 2 decimal digits

Tags: javascript, rounding-error

In my project, when I am subtracting **96.74** from **60**, javascript is giving me **36.739999999999995** , but I need **36.74** to do further calculation.

What should I do, how do I overcome this problem??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code did you try? It's hard to give an answer when you don't know what hasn't worked. Are you having an error with Math.round()? :)

Comment: Am I the only one that expects -36.74 when I subtract 96.74 from 60?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseFloat` and set the decimal places to 2 with `.toFixed(2)`

```js
console.log(parseFloat(36.739999999999995).toFixed(2))
```

If you want to get rid of trailing zeroes cast the result to a `Number`:

```js
var num = Number(parseFloat(36.7).toFixed(2));
console.log(num);
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for this case, but I am performing this operation on a array and not all numbers have 2 precision after decimal. I will test with different data sets and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Example how to round to **two decimals**, if that was what you wanted?

```js
 var x = 36.739999999999995;

 x = Math.round(x*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2);

 console.log(x);
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for this case, but I am performing this operation on a array and not all numbers have 2 precision after decimal. I will test with different data sets and let you know